# Windows Phone 7 parse this item of xml

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

How can I parse this image with XDocument?

```
<enclosure length="1234" type="image/jpeg" url="http://asd.com/media/picture/1/80/71/3223wee.jpg" />
```

my rss look like this

```
<item>
 <title>aaa</title>
 <desc>aaa</desc>
 <enclosure length="3234" type="image/jpeg" url="http://asd.com/media/picture/1/80/71/1223wee.jpg" />

</item>

<item>
 <title>aaa</title>
 <desc>aaa</desc>
 <enclosure length="1234" type="image/jpeg" url="http://asd.com/media/picture/1/80/71/3223wee.jpg" />

</item>
```

**edited:**

The working, correct code:

```
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
            var data = from query in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                       select new Cikk
                       {
                           Title        = (query.Element("title") == null) ? "" : (string)query.Element("title").Value.ToString().Replace("<![CDATA[", "").Replace("]]>", ""),
                           Description  = (query.Element("description").Value.Equals("")) ? "" : (string)query.Element("description").Value.ToString().Replace("<![CDATA[", "").Replace("]]>", "").Substring(0, 20) + "...",
                           Source       = (query.Element("enclosure") == null) ? "" : (string)query.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value
                       };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by "parse this image" but you can get the individual bits easily:

```
XElement element = /* for example */ item.Element("enclosure");

int length = (int) element.Attribute("length");
string type = (string) element.Attribute("type");
string url = (string) element.Attribute("url");
```

If that doesn't help, please clarify your question.